# Whats the most pythonic way to order calls to an objects methods without

Tags: python, methods

When you give a developer a "robs_numbers" object, the developer can call the various filters in any order they want e.g. obj.filter1().filter2().filtern() ..

However generally the more numbers I filter out early, the faster the filtering is.

**I want the developer to be able to call the filter() methods in any order they want**.
The developer then gets back a robs_numbers object (or perhaps an iterable..).
**However I want my methods (filters) to actually run in the order given by priority().**

technically priority() should take the pair filter: [args], so that I can use any filter. priority() will then return the priority value

Here is some sample code, though you may change the object completely if it's more pythonic:

```
from random import randint
data = [randint(0,100) for i in range(100)]

class robs_numbers():
    def __init__(self,numbers,_min,_max):
        self.numbers = iter(numbers)
        self._min = _min #approx
        self._max = _max #approx

    def bigger(self,x):
        print "priority = ", self.priority(x)
        return robs_numbers([i for i in self.numbers if i>x],x,self._max)

    def smaller(self,x):
        print "priority = ", self.priority(x)
        return robs_numbers([i for i in self.numbers if i<x],self._min,x)

    def order(self,backwards=False):
        print "priority = ", self.priority()
        self.numbers = iter(sorted(self.numbers,reverse=backwards))
        return self

    # ...
    # More filter methods
    # ...

    def priority(self,x=None):
        #works out the order methods should be called to increase efficiency
        if x is None:
            return 99999
        else:
            return abs(x-(self._max-self._min)/2)
```

and example of two valid uses, however I want them both to be fast, right now only one is efficient:

```
def get():
    return robs_numbers(data,0,100)

rf = get().bigger(80).smaller(90).order() #faster in this order
print list(rf.numbers), rf._min, rf._max

#priority =  30
#priority =  80
#priority =  99999
#[81, 81, 82, 83, 85, 86, 87, 87, 89] 80 90


rf = get().order().smaller(90).bigger(80) #slower in this order
print list(rf.numbers), rf._min, rf._max
#priority =  99999
#priority =  40
#priority =  35
#[81, 81, 82, 83, 85, 86, 87, 87, 89] 80 90
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to create some kind of lazily evaluated query set, and only execute all the filters whenever the developer calls `list()` or something else that requires you to export the data to another object.  [Django](http://djangoproject.com/) has a good example of this in their query sets, [which are lazy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy).

So, you could write something to the effect of

```
class RobsNumbers(object):
    def __init__(self, numbers, min, max):
        self._numbers = numbers
        self._min = min
        self._max = max
        self._filters = []

    def bigger(self, x):
        new_obj = RobsNumbers(self._numbers, x, self._max)
        new_obj._filters = self._filters + [GreaterThanFilter(x)]
        return new_obj

    # Other filter methods simply add a filter to the _filters list of the object

    def __iter__(self):
        # Here is the complicated optimization logic to reorder and execute the filters
        pass
```

Note that this code does **zero filtering** until the developer asks for the data contained inside a `RobsNumbers` object, so it is quite lazy.

Comment: Thanks, this looks fairly simple. I'm just looking up "lazy" at the moment. It would probably still work even if they consumed an itertools.islice() before adding further filters ;p